# Group By and Order By in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I just need to order my records according to updated, and then group them according to card_id.

**This is my code:**

```php
$triages = Triyage::latest('updated_at')->groupBy('card_id')->paginate(8);

return view('Admin.Opd.card_opd', compact('triages'));
```

Comment: You want the latest record for each `card_id` value?

Comment: Jonas Staudenmeir yes sir

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery JOIN:

```php
$join = Triyage::select('card_id', DB::raw('max(updated_at) updated_at'))
    ->groupBy('card_id');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as latest';
$triages = Triyage::join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
    $join->on('triyages.card_id', 'latest.card_id')
        ->on('triyages.updated_at', 'latest.updated_at');
    })->paginate(8);
```